# What exactly does the 'from' parameter in animationController.forward() do in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm having a hard time understanding what exactly are the differences between the `begin` parameter of the Tween class, the `lowerBound` parameter of the `AnimationController` class, and the `from` parameter of the `forward()` function which is called on the animationController object in the code snippet.
Which parameter controls which aspect(s) of the animation? Thanks in advance.

```
  Animation animation;
  AnimationController animationController;

  HomeScreenState();


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this,duration: Duration(seconds: 1),/*lowerBound,upperBound*/);
    animationController.addListener((){

      if(animationController.isCompleted){
        animationController.reverse();
      } else if(animationController.isDismissed){
        animationController.forward();
      }
      setState(() {

      });
    });
    animationController.forward(/*from:*/);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    animation = CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: Curves.easeInOut);
    animation = Tween(begin: -0.5,end: 0.5).animate(animation);
    //other code
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter `from` of `AnimationController.forward` is used when you want to play the animation from a point other than the current position.

You could compare it to the `?t=timestamp` parameter of youtube videos, which allows starting the video at a very specific time.

To not confuse with `Tween.begin`, which corresponds to how the animation should look like at the very beginning of the animation

Comment: "other than the very beginning" - shouldn't it be "from the current position"?

Comment: @pskink Ah yes, my bad. Fixed